# Routing issues after updating to Angular 6.1

Tags: angular, routes

The routing of my application worked as intended before I updated Angular from 4.1 to 6.1, but now I can't make sense of what I'm doing wrong.
When I navigate to root route '/' it somehow matches with my '/users' route and does not include my LayoutComponent that is my master detail component.

Here's my routers:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthorizeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tickets/ticket',
        loadChildren: 'app/ticket/ticket.module#TicketModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'tickets/department',
        loadChildren: 'app/ticket-department/ticket-department.module#TicketDepartmentModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tickets/category',
        loadChildren: 'app/ticket-category/ticket-category.module#TicketCategoryModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'stores',
        loadChildren: 'app/store/store.module#StoreModule'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'set-password',
    component: SetPasswordParentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'error-pages',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**ticket.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TicketComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TicketListComponent,
        resolve: { tickets: TicketListResolver }
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddTicketComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':ticketId/edit',
        component: EditTicketComponent,
        resolve: { ticket: TicketEditResolver }
      },
      {
        path: ':ticketId/details',
        component: TicketDetailsComponent,
        resolve: { ticket: TicketDetailsResolver, user: TicketDetailsUserResolver }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**ticket-department.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TicketDepartmentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TicketDepartmentListComponent,
        resolve: { departments: TicketDepartmentListResolver }
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddTicketDepartmentComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':departmentId/edit',
        component: EditTicketDepartmentComponent,
        resolve: { department: EditTicketDepartmentResolver }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

**ticket-category.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TicketCategoryComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TicketCategoryListComponent,
        resolve: { categories: TicketCategoryListResolver }
        // outlet: 'ticket-category-outlet'
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddTicketCategoryComponent,
        resolve: { departments: AddTicketCategoryResolver }
      },
      {
        path: ':ticketCategoryId/edit',
        component: EditTicketCategoryComponent,
        resolve: {
          category: EditTicketCategoryResolver,

        }
        // outlet: 'ticket-category-outlet'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

**user.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UserListComponent,
        resolve: { users: UserListResolver }
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddUserComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':userId/edit',
        component: EditUserComponent,
        resolve: { user: EditUserResolver }
      },
      {
        path: ':userId/details',
        component: UserDetailsComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

**store.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: StoreComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: StoreListComponent,
        resolve: { stores: StoreListResolver }
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: StoreAddComponent
      },

      {
        path: ':storeId/edit',
        component: StoreEditComponent,
        resolve: { store: StoreEditResolver }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

I'm using Augury in Chrome to view my router tree and that looks like this:

[image: Augury Route tree]

But the tree that I want looks something like this:

[image: Expected Route tree]

The root route should go to HomeComponent. I've tried removing the imports of the lazy-loaded modules in my root module, but then I get an error message saying that it can't find the components in those modules.
Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this by changing a few things:

First I changed all loadChildren lines in `app-routing.module.ts` from

`loadChildren: 'app/ticket/ticket.module#TicketModule'`

to

`loadChildren: () => TicketModule`

Then, for some reason, I had to name all my root routes in my childrouting modules like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tickets',
    component: TicketComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TicketListComponent,
        resolve: { tickets: TicketListResolver },
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddTicketComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':ticketId/edit',
        component: EditTicketComponent,
        resolve: { ticket: TicketEditResolver }
      },
      {
        path: ':ticketId/details',
        component: TicketDetailsComponent,
        resolve: { ticket: TicketDetailsResolver, user: TicketDetailsUserResolver }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

Now, the routing works as intended.